# Non Ascii Unicode Encode and Decode in java

Tags: java, android, unicode, encode

How we can do programmatically in java "Non-ASCII Unicode encoding".
input is: "abc ആന" 
and output should be :
"abc \u0d06\u0d28"

Note:- Ascii and space characters not converted to Unicode character
all other characters will be Encoded.

we need this conversion because Server does not support non-ascii characters.

Comment: for example `Uri.encode()` / `URLEncoder.encode()`

Comment: This is done with a litle method that replaces all non-ascii characters by their unicode escape sequence (don't forget to escape the backslash as well or your encoding will not be bijective). Show us what you already did and where it broke down.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change server side encode to UTF-8 which will support in MySql Database

and on android side, you also need to encode those characters in UTF-8, becouse the characters (`ആന`) is in UTF-8

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(2500);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");//<- and here !!!
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

if(jsonObject!=null) {
    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));//<- and here !!!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering .. wheather this problem is solved in android side only .like converting the Non ascii character to unicode.